# Floating Action Button overlaps Tab Title

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, floating-action-button

Things that I tried but didn't work

- Have a negative padding to move the FAB a bit down. But the padding didn't make any effect
- Tab style to make the gravity and layout gravity = "top" , this made no effect.

Also tried to change the FAB with size mini, this one works but I would like to keep the button with the same size.

Any suggestions?

[image: overlap]

`

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:id="@+id/materialup.tabs"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fillViewport="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/play"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/materialup.tabs"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center|right"/>`
```

This is the tab style

```
<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

I am trying to achieve something like this

[image: Overlap fixed]

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this problem?

Comment: Not really, I ended up using a custom FAB with size mini.

Answer (score 0):

Use CoordinatorLayout it helps to manage your child views

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />
        <!-- The Tab rests directly below the Toolbar, attached below it -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <!-- Helps handing the Fragments to load for each Tab -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager />
```

Comment: That's what I am using. The problem is more that the FAB is anchor to the TABS in the center, but it overlaps the title so  I want to move some pixels down the FAB or move the Tab title a bit up .

Comment: can you post the screen of tabs how you want to desgin

Comment: I have added the image of what I am trying to achieve.